# How to load triplets from a csv-file into MarkLogic?

Tags: csv, marklogic, triples, marklogic-8

What I am starting with, is the postcode table from the netherlands. I split it up into a couple of csv files, containing for instance the city as subject, PartOf as predicate and municipality as object. This gives you this in a file:

```
city,PartOf,municipality
Meppel,PartOf,Meppel
Nijeveen,PartOf,Meppel
Rogat,PartOf,Meppel
```

Now I would like to get this data into MarkLogic. And I can import csv-files, I can import triples, but I can't figure out the combination.

Comment: Please add an example of the CSV and what you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rewriting it slightly so it conforms to the [N-Triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Triples) format, giving it the .nt extension, and then using MLCP to load it as input_type rdf.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Refine](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-refine/) to convert CSV data to RDF. After that, MLCP can be used to push that data. You can do something like this -

```
$ mlcp.sh import -username user -password password -host localhost \
    -port 8000 -input_file_path /my/data -mode local \
    -input_file_type rdf
```

For more on loading triples using MLCP you can refer [this MarkLogic Community Page](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_32771)